# Where to define context data object for L20n?

Tags: l20n

I need to provide some context to the localization files. I've read I can provide a context data object (http://l20n.org/learn/using-external-variables-in-translations/), but I have no idea where to store it. Is it attached to the DOM ? Provided with the l20n api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to provide it as another data attribute, alongside data-l10n-id.

```
<div data-l10n-id='promotion_after_amount_text' data-l10n-args='{"amount":"1.5"}'></div>
```